# Writing a dict to a CSV using Bonobo-ETL

Tags: python, etl, export-to-csv, bonobo-etl

I'm trying Bonobo, taking a data source in dict format and then writing to a CSV file.

However, when I yield a dict to bononbo.CsvWriter, the result is a single field containing the dict represented as a string.

This can be replicated using a conversion script:

```
graph = bonobo.Graph(
    bonobo.LdjsonReader('test.jsonl'),
    bonobo.CsvWriter('test.csv'),
)
```

Similarly, explicitly using a dict will have the same result:

```
graph = bonobo.Graph(
lambda: {'header': 'test'},
bonobo.CsvWriter('test.csv'),
)
```

The result of the above will be

```
{'header': 'test'}
```

rather than the expected

```
header
test
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Use a bonobo.UnpackItems(0) node in the middle.

```
graph = bonobo.Graph(
    bonobo.LdjsonReader(jsonld_input_file),
    bonobo.UnpackItems(0),
    bonobo.CsvWriter(csv_output_file),
)
```

**Why is this happening?**

The input/output of graph nodes are always normalized to some kind of tuple during the communication phase (aka, the queues that let nodes talk).

When you yield a dict, it's normalized to a one-item tuple of this dict (yield {} is equivalent to yield ({}, ), in a bonobo graph execution context).

The Writer will then write the string representation, using the dict-in-a-tuple input. Hence your result.

**bonobo.UnpackItems(...)**

UnpackItems(...) node will take some arguments from its input stream elements and "unpack" them (transform the content of an arg into top level value, in the output tuple. The dict keys will be used to make it a namedtuple-like object, keeping the necessary headers for later write.

Arguments are 'indexes' of the items your interested in unpacking. For example, given this input line: ({"foo": 1}, {"bar": 2}, {"baz":3}), if you pass this through a UnpackItems(0, 2) node, you'll get (foo=1, bar=3) as the output (last notation is meta, it's of namedtuple type).

Reference should live at http://docs.bonobo-project.org/en/develop/reference/api/bonobo/nodes.html#bonobo.nodes.UnpackItems but I agree it's a bit lacking details for now.